# How to skip Flask cache on template errors

Tags: python, flask, redis

I'm using Flask with template caching on a Redis server:

```
TIMEOUT = 60 * 60
cache = Cache(app.server, config={
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'redis',
    'CACHE_REDIS_HOST': "myredis",
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': TIMEOUT,
    'CACHE_REDIS_PORT': 6379,
})
# to disable caching
#app.config["CACHE_TYPE"] = "null"
```

and then with the @cache decorator like

```
@cache.memoize(timeout=TIMEOUT)
def update_date():
    return manager.getData()
```

The problem is that when `manager.getData()` has errors or no data the decorator will cache the response anyways. How to avoid it?

**[UPDATE]**

I have tried using the `unless` parameter, that according to the docs it should be

```
unless – Default None. Cache will always execute the caching facilities unelss this callable is true. This will bypass the caching entirely.
```

so used like

```
@cache.memoize(timeout=TIMEOUT unless=DataLoader.instance.hasData)
    def update_date():
        return manager.getData()
```

where `DataLoader` is a Singleton instance and `hasData` method will return `None` if has no data or `True` if it has data, so the method `getData` would compute the data and return instance variable `self.data` that holds always last computed data or `None`.

```
class DataLoader(SingletonMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.data=None
    def hasData(self):
        if self.data is Not None:
            return True
        else:
            return None
    def getData(self):
        # calculate data
        res = self.computeData()
        if res is not None:
            self.data=res
        return self.data
```

but it seems it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when manager.getData() has errors or no data the decorator will cache the response anyways. How to avoid it?

Have you checked that? If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/sh4nks/flask-caching/blob/master/flask_caching/__init__.py#L756) (I assume you are using `flask-caching` because `flask-cache` is not maintained for over 4 years) if you get `None` from cache (`rv` value) you don't use it, you call your `f` function. If `f` function raises exception nothing is saved to cache.

Comment: ok so basically the `getData` could raise a custom error like `raise ValueError('no data available')`.

Comment: Yes, You can catch exceptions with `@app.errorhandler(Exception)` and gracefully display errors.